PhotoPicker cannot pick longer video and stuck with progress
I followed Apple example of pick single video from photo lib:
    @Published var videoSelection: PhotosPickerItem? = nil {
        didSet {
            if let videoSelection {
                let progress = loadTransferable(from: videoSelection)
                
                videoState = .loading(progress)
            } else {
                videoState = .empty
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum VideoState {
        case empty, loading(Progress), success(URL), failure(any Error)
    }
    @Published var videoState: VideoState? {
        didSet {
            print(videoState)
        }
    }

with
    private func loadTransferable(from videoSelection: PhotosPickerItem) -> Progress {
        return videoSelection.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) { result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard videoSelection == self.videoSelection else {
                    print("Failed to get the selected item.")
                    return
                }
                switch result {
                    case .success(let video?):
                        self.videoState = .success(video.fileUrl)
                    case .success(nil):
                        self.videoState = .empty
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.videoState = .failure(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

and I can see the progress being created:
Optional(Sync_Cam.WrappedVideoPlayerModel.VideoState.loading(<NSProgress: 0x3011a5100> : Parent: 0x0 (portion: 0) / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 0  ))

But it just stuck there. Progress always stays 0 and things in DispatchQueue.main.async is never called for longer videos. For shorter videos there were no progresses, the videos were instantly transferred and usable. But for longer ones the progresses stuck.
What might be the cause? All the videos I tested are not on iCloud.
